# XPATH in XSLT - DITA XML files

Tags: dita

I have a XML called "map.xml" which calls another xml "map1.xml".Map.xml has reference to map.xsl.

In XSLT, i need to write the code to get the node value present in map1.xml? Can anyone of you please suggest a solution for this?

Below code specific to DITA standards

map1.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <!-- code to refer XSLT -->
          <map title="DITA Topic Map">
  <topicref href="client.xml"/>
       </map>
```

map2.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <concept id="map2">
 <title>Client Rights</title>
 <conbody>
  <p>Part of your job as a healthcare provider.</p>
 </conbody>
       </concept>
```

Comment: DITA follows its own convention for topics linking, not XPath nor XPointer. Check http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.0/dita-v1.0-spec-os-ArchitecturalSpecification.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Using the XSLT document() function looks like the way to go.

For example, to get the content/value of the p element in map2.xml:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('map2.xml')/concept/conbody/p"/>
```

Have not tested this on your example, but that's what I would try!

Answer (score 1):

Use the XSLT document() function to access nodes in a separate XML document. A simple example (courtesy of w3schools.com) can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp).

I'm a new user, so SO is preventing me from posting a second link in my answer. Here's the best I can do: the XSLT standard's explanation of document() can be found at www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the sources should actually look like this (with a reference to a DTD or a schema, not to a styleheet):

map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">
<map title="DITA Topic Map">
  <topicref href="client.xml"/>
</map>
```

client.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id="client.xml">
 <title>Client Rights</title>
 <conbody>
  <p>Part of your job as a healthcare provider.</p>
 </conbody>
</concept>
```

David's suggestion is correct, it gives you the following result:

```
Part of your job as a healthcare provider.
```

To refine on this: To make use of DITA's specialization feature, you'd rather use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' map/topicref ') and @href]">
    <xsl:variable name="topic" select="document(@href, .)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$topic//*[contains(@class, ' topic/p ')]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the sample data, this leads to the same result. But if you had a specialized paragraph element <myp> derived from <p>, you could still use the same transformation for the new element.